# Run asp.net application under domain account without joining the domain?

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, windowsdomainaccount

My feeling says it's not posible but anyway I am curious if there is at least a workaround for accomplish this.

Basically I am working at my client site and my machine is not connected to the domain.
What I want to do is running a web application locally under a domain account, and using the webdev server.
The webapp uses the default authentication, windows authentication that is.
I tried using impersonation with domain\user & password but I got the following error

*Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.*

I have to mention that the username and the password are correct.

Thanks in advance 
Iulian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot access the domain controller (or your computer does not know what domain controller to use), there is no way finding out if the password is correct or not. What normally Windows does, is asking the DC "does this password match this account" (simply speaking). Now in your scenario, there is no DC. Hence, "unknown username".

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. So, I assume, the only way is to join the domain controller.

Comment: Yes. What you can do after joining the domain, is disconnect your computer from that network. In this case the cached credentials will be used.

Comment: @naivists Hi, I use this - connect to network, login in the windows as a domain user, start using the application - but once the computer gets disconnected from the network I get the 'The trust relationship between workstation and domain failed' error, even tho it is possible to login to the computer using these credentials. Any idea how to fix it? Thank you :)